Im doing project esp32 using micropython haivng problem with my turbidity sensor
from machine import Pin, ADC
import time

# Inisialisasi pin ADC (misalnya, GPIO 34)
adc_pin = ADC(Pin(34))
adc_pin.atten(ADC.ATTN_11DB)  # Set attenuation untuk rentang tegangan yang lebih besar (0-3.3V)
adc_pin.width(ADC.WIDTH_12BIT)  # Set resolusi ADC ke 12-bit

# Kalibrasi sensor (contoh, sesuaikan dengan sensor Anda)
# Misalnya, berdasarkan datasheet:
# NTU = a * voltage + b
a = -1120.4  # Koefisien slope
b = 5742.3   # Intercept

def read_turbidity():
    # Baca nilai analog dari sensor kekeruhan
    adc_value = adc_pin.read()
    # Konversi nilai ADC ke tegangan (dalam Volt)
    voltage = adc_value / 4095.0 * 3.3
    # Konversi tegangan ke NTU menggunakan rumus kalibrasi
    ntu = a * voltage + b
    return adc_value, voltage, ntu

while True:
    adc_value, voltage, ntu = read_turbidity()
    print("ADC Value:", adc_value, "Voltage:", voltage, "V", "Turbidity:", ntu, "NTU")
    time.sleep(1)

anyone know the problem because the ADC output was unstable, even my turbidity was dry the output keep changing
this is my output
ADC Value: 0 Voltage: 0.0 V Turbidity: 5742.3 NTU
ADC Value: 48 Voltage: 0.03868132 V Turbidity: 5698.961 NTU
ADC Value: 269 Voltage: 0.2167766 V Turbidity: 5499.423 NTU
ADC Value: 411 Voltage: 0.3312088 V Turbidity: 5371.213 NTU
ADC Value: 880 Voltage: 0.7091575 V Turbidity: 4947.76 NTU
ADC Value: 1594 Voltage: 1.284542 V Turbidity: 4303.099 NTU
ADC Value: 1520 Voltage: 1.224908 V Turbidity: 4369.912 NTU
ADC Value: 1609 Voltage: 1.29663 V Turbidity: 4289.556 NTU
ADC Value: 1569 Voltage: 1.264396 V Turbidity: 4325.671 NTU
ADC Value: 1344 Voltage: 1.083077 V Turbidity: 4528.82 NTU
ADC Value: 1022 Voltage: 0.8235897 V Turbidity: 4819.55 NTU
ADC Value: 766 Voltage: 0.6172894 V Turbidity: 5050.689 NTU
ADC Value: 558 Voltage: 0.4496704 V Turbidity: 5238.489 NTU
ADC Value: 432 Voltage: 0.3481319 V Turbidity: 5352.253 NTU
ADC Value: 269 Voltage: 0.2167766 V Turbidity: 5499.423 NTU
ADC Value: 31 Voltage: 0.02498168 V Turbidity: 5714.311 NTU
ADC Value: 0 Voltage: 0.0 V Turbidity: 5742.3 NTU
ADC Value: 0 Voltage: 0.0 V Turbidity: 5742.3 NTU
ADC Value: 0 Voltage: 0.0 V Turbidity: 5742.3 NTU
ADC Value: 16 Voltage: 0.01289377 V Turbidity: 5727.854 NTU
please help mee finish it, i really hope your help
